# Divs not centred when stacking in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm putting together a test site with Bootstrap and think I'm misunderstanding the grid system somewhere. I have the following code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-12 text-center">
      <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="cheryl-winn-boujnida-65955.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <h4 class="card-title">
          <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch" aria-hidden="true"></i> Fast photo printing</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Upload content and have it sent to your address within 3 hours</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-12 text-center">
      <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="neonbrand-371471.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <h4 class="card-title">
          <i class="fa fa-superpowers" aria-hidden="true"></i> Total access</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Access your media from any device, from any location</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
      <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="allef-vinicius-205147.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <h4 class="card-title">
          <i class="fa fa-ravelry" aria-hidden="true"></i> Freedom
        </h4>
        <p class="card-text">Choose your package to suit your needs and usage</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On a large screen the divs line up nicely horizontally and then they do indeed stack at the first break point. However when they stack they align to the left and I also had the impression that by adding the `col-12` (as I understand this has replaced `col-xs-12`) that they would also take up the full width of the screen but this is not happening either.

Comment: so you want them to be in the center and take the full width, is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

CENTER CHILD ELEMENT IN ROW

**1. Adding Class**

Go to the child element of the col-sm/md/lg-6/12 and give it class of 'center-block'

> But it's for Bootstrap>3.0.0

Example:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="child center-block">
</div>
```

**2. Margin Auto**

Give the element you want to center the following property

```
.className{
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

Solution to your problem is below:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">


    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 text-center">

      <div class="card center-block" style="width: 20rem;">


        <img class="card-img-top img-responsive" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/01/10/23/image-1635747_960_720.jpg" alt="Card image cap">


        <h4 class="card-title">

          <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch" aria-hidden="true"></i> Fast photo printing</h4>

        <p class="card-text">Upload content and have it sent to your address within 3 hours</p>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 text-center">

      <div class="card center-block" style="width: 20rem;">

        <img class="card-img-top img-responsive" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/06/23/21/soap-bubble-1959327_960_720.jpg" alt="Card image cap">

        <h4 class="card-title">

          <i class="fa fa-superpowers" aria-hidden="true"></i> Total access</h4>

        <p class="card-text">Access your media from any device, from any location</p>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 text-center">

      <div class="card center-block" style="width: 20rem;">

        <img class="card-img-top img-responsive" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/29/10/07/animal-1868911_960_720.jpg" alt="Card image cap">

        <h4 class="card-title">

          <i class="fa fa-ravelry" aria-hidden="true"></i> Freedom

        </h4>

        <p class="card-text">Choose your package to suit your needs and usage</p>

      </div>

    </div>

    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: If you find this answer as correct please mark it correct as well.
Thanks!